# cakephp - datepicker bootstrap not populate when use a edit action

Tags: php, cakephp, edit

I'm using a datepicker for bootstrap in my application. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="input-append date pull-right" id="dp3" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
   <input name="dataregisto" id="dataregisto" class="span2" size="16" type="text" readonly>
   <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

So when I save the data, it works normally, but when I edit a record the date doesn't show. 
On the other hand, all remaining data are populated.
My JavaScript code:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var today = new Date();
        var t = today.getDate() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getFullYear();
        $("#dp3").datepicker()
                .on('show', function(ev) {

            $('#dp3').data({date: t}).datepicker('update');
        });

         //    $('#timepicker1').timepicker();


        document.getElementById("dataregisto").value = document.getElementById("dataregisto").defaultValue = t;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

CONTROLLER

```
 function edit($id = null) {

    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) { /* verifica se existe uma sessão */
        $this->Registo->id = $id;
        if (empty($this->data)) {
            /* acede aos projetos */
            $this->set('projects', $this->Registo->Project->find('list', array('fields' => array('pname'))));
            /* acede ás versoes do projecto a editar */
            $this->set('projectversions', $this->requestAction("/ProjectVersions/getversionsofproject", array('projects' => $this->Registo->read()['Registo']['projects'])));
            /* acede aos clientes */
            $this->set('clients', $this->requestAction("/CustomFieldOptions/getClients"));
            /* acede ás issuetypes */
            // $issuetype= $this->requestAction("/Projects/getissuetypeofproject", array('projects' => $this->Registo->read()['Registo']['projects']));

            $this->set('dataregisto', $this->Registo->read()['Registo']['dataregisto']);
            /*  $issuetype = array();

              foreach($IssueTypes as $value) {
              $value = $value['IssueType']['id'];
              $issuetype[$value['IssueType']['id']] = $value['IssueType']['pname'];
              }


              debug($issuetype); */

            $this->set('issuetype', $issuetype);
            $this->request->data = $this->Registo->read();
        } else {
            if ($this->Registo->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Registo alterado com sucesso', true), 'flash_success');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $errors = $this->Registo->invalidFields();
                $this->Messages->customize_error_msg($errors['issuetype']);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
        // $this->Session->setFlash(__('Por favor efetue LOGIN para poder aceder a esta página!', true), 'flash_success');
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the PHP from your controller action

Comment: do you really want your input#dataregisto as "readonly" ?

Comment: yes, i really want 'read only'... why?

Comment: i already update  fullybaked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are you sure, you save your inserted data, eg. in a MySQL database in
>   the dd-mm-yyyy format? That could be the solution or you detected a
>   bug.

Edit: Take a look to the [documentation](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var today = new Date(),
t = today.getDate() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getFullYear();
        $("#dp3").datepicker().on('show', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).datepicker('setValue', t);
        });
        document.getElementById("dataregisto").value = document.getElementById("dataregisto").defaultValue = t;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: no... but I modified it, and doesnt work.


the data is saved 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

<div class="input-append date pull-right" id="dp3" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
   <input name="dataregisto" id="dataregisto" class="span2" size="16" type="text"  readonly>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>

Comment: Please explain your question again. I don't get it.

Comment: user1232375 I'm not able to get the date value that comes from $ this-> Registration-> read () (to edit a record) and put it in my view.

Comment: Try var_dump($this->Registration->read()) and post me the output!

Comment: array(7) { ["Registo"]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> int(23) ["projects"]=> string(5) "10000" ["projectversions"]=> NULL ["clients"]=> string(5) "10001" ["issuetype"]=> string(1) "0" ["categories"]=> NULL ["tempo"]=> string(8) "01:15:00" ["dataregisto"]=> string(10) "2013-05-15" ["comentario"]=> string(13) "teste sucesso" ["userid"]=> NULL } ["Project"]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> string(5) "10000" ["pname"]=> string(5) "ISPUP" ["url"]=> NULL ["lead"]=> string(7) "amendes" ["description"]=> string(428) "